# How do I stop Apache/Tomcat server on localhost://8080?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I keep getting errors when trying to serve files locally. I am using Tomcat on port 8080.

When using Eclipse, I get the following error message:

> Several ports (8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

---

### Question

How do I stop the server on port 8080 if I don't know which process started it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go with a web browser to:

**localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080**
and 
**localhost:8009 or 127.0.0.1:8009**

There you could see which service is running on those ports.

Then it will be more simple to understand what you have to stop.

**EDIT:**
You could use a prompt and the command:

```
netstat -b
```

-b it will show the name of the executable running on a port.

For understanding how it works [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx) a good explanation.

Comment: You wrote: *"There you could see which service is running on those ports."* ...But **HOW** would I do that?